# Hyperlink has double underline

Tags: html, css

I have hyperlink on my web page. For some reason there are 2 lines underneath when I hover over the link. I have been able to remove one of the lines using `text-decoration: none` in CSS. The bottom line is the problem. I notice there is a single grey line (the lower of the two) if there is no hover, hard to see though. See attached image.

HTML

```
 <a href="http://www.mywebpage.com/" class="no-underline">My Web Page</a>
```

CSS

```
.no-underline:hover {text-decoration: none}
```

[image]

Comment: Provide your link please

Comment: Inspect your element in the DevTool of your browser, look at the computed tab to see where the underline is coming from.

Comment: This could be `border` overriding from another css rule.

Comment: Check if you have any CSS for a(href) where border bottom is set.

Comment: Are you using a CSS reset in your code?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can someone please tell me why I keep getting negative marks on this forum?

Comment: shi: No CSS with bottom border set ... Abhishej Pandey: there are no overriding borders ... Nail: no link as design is in progress ... Dani: I will inspect however that may be done

Comment: @id11 Read Paulie_D's comment, you will understand why you're getting negative votes.

Comment: My issue is that I may get knocked off the forum because I am asking what seems to be unreasonable questions. I remember I asked a few questions a couple of years ago and almost always got negative marks. Can understand the formatting/presentation issue, that's my fault. But actual questions are not that stupid are they. -6 marks after a short time already?

Comment: In this case, your problem doesn't contain the minimum code needed to solve the problem. The solution to your problem is likely another CSS class that you have used within your code that is being applied to the link that we aren't seeing. In this case, you should post all your HTML and all your CSS, b/c it's the only way we'll be able to see and help you.

Comment: OK thanks I will bear that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by a few above, it was the border. Below works I guess. @Dani tip to inspect element, cheers for that.

```
.no-underline:hover {text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 0}
```

Will have to tread carefully next post.

Answer (score 1):

.no-underline:hover {text-decoration: none !important;border:none !important;}
.no-underline {text-decoration: none !important;border:none !important;}